# Having issues outputting msgbox in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I'm running a script that performs multiple checks on a Windows machine before running a program. I'm running a VBScript script that checks things such as *patch status, firewall status*, and antivirus software status. After the script runs, the information needs to be output so the end user can fix any issues that arise. This needs to be output in a single message box that shows everything that is not compliant on the end users machine.

Right now after the script runs I'm getting multiple boxes for output, and none of them are displaying the names of what needs to be fixed. I'm just getting the information in quotes in the dialog box.

```
errors = Array(strSUpdate,strFirewallStatus,strProdState)
Dim errorfix

For Each item In errors
    set errorfix = errorfix & item & vbnewline
    if (errors = "Off") Then
        msgbox "Compliance Check results" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "The following requires attention" & vbNewLine & errorfix & vbNewLine & _
        "Press OK to Continue", 0, "Moka 5 Compliance Check"
    Else
        msgbox "Compliance Check results" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Everything looks good." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Press OK to Continue", 0, "Moka 5 Compliance Check"
    End if
Next
```

Comment: I don't think you want the message box *inside* the loop, could that be?

Comment: @tomalak You're correct I didn't. I think what I'm looking for is a way to create variables is the condition in the array exists. So if "strSUpdate" and "strFirewallStatus" are "Off" then it will create two new variables and output those. so I'd be looking at the line 'For Each item In errors' and 'if (errors = "Off") Then' it will create a variable for each that matches that condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to avoid arrays altogether and use the much more convenient [dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) instead.

If nothing else you will create much more readable code that way, but they are also a lot more powerful than arrays.

```
Option Explicit

Dim errors
Set errors = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' fill the dictionary troughout your program. Fill in just the 
' actionables and don't insert the stuff that's okay.
errors("Firewall Status") = "Off"
errors("This other thing") = "Missing"

If errors.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Compliance Check results" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
           "Everything looks good." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
           "Press OK to Continue", vbOkOnly, "Moka 5 Compliance Check"
Else
    Dim item, toFix

    For Each item In errors
        toFix = toFix & " - " & item & " is " & errors(item) & vbNewLine
    Next

    Msgbox "Compliance Check results" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
           "The following requires attention:" & vbNewLine & _
           toFix & vbNewLine & _
           "Press OK to Continue", 0, "Moka 5 Compliance Check"
End If
```

Comment: Throughout my script I've set IF statements for the variables; strSUpdate, strFirewallStatus, and strProdState. Is it possible to add these variables to the dictionary, and pull them out if they are set as "Off"?

Comment: If you ask like that: Sure. :) It's just somewhat... futile to create a dictionary entry and then ignore it if has a certain value. See the comment in my code. It's never too late to refactor your script.

Comment: Good to hear! Be advised that there is one issue with dictionaries: They don't have a guaranteed order of iteration (as opposed to arrays). If you need to keep a certain stable order, you're back to arrays, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get the return value from the msgbox, i.e., `tempresponse = Msgbox("")`. [The link is here](http://ss64.com/vb/msgbox.html)

```
errors = Array(strSUpdate,strFirewallStatus,strProdState)
Dim errorfix, tempresponse

For Each item In errors
    set errorfix = errorfix & item & vbnewline
    if (errors = "Off") Then
        tempresponse = msgbox ("Compliance Check results" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "The following requires attention" & vbNewLine & errorfix & vbNewLine & _
        "Press OK to Continue", 0, "Moka 5 Compliance Check")
    Else
        tempresponse = msgbox ("Compliance Check results" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Everything looks good." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Press OK to Continue", 0, "Moka 5 Compliance Check")
    End if
Next
```

As @Tomalak has said, after each iteration you will need to clear the msgbox. Would a `popup` [work better, as it will clear the message after x seconds](http://ss64.com/vb/popup.html).